# Find out the columns which got changed when comparing two tables in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table TableA with 10 columns having around 4000 rows.
After done some calculations there were some changes in the table. To get those changes I first took the back up before calculations and then after calculations.
So now I have 2 tables TableA_backup1 and TableA_backup2.
Now I need to know which columns specifically changed in the rows using the above  2 tables.

Any help?

Comment: Which sql language are you using? Add a tag

Comment: @George Menoutis Do you have an automated script or so to add that reply to any question tagged 'SQL' ?  If a question is perfectly answerable in standard SQL, there is just no reason to force askers to limit their question to a specific dialect.

Comment: I hope you have a primary key.

Comment: microsoft sql server

Comment: yes I have a primary key

Comment: @Erwin First, I think your comment violates the "Be nice" thing of SO. Second, supposing the OP's tables have a large enough number of columns that they don't want to type (which is more probable to be the case since they resorted to posting a question here), I guess system tables and dynamic sql would come in handy. As far as I know, system tables are not present in the sql standard. Thirdly, adding a tag might attract answerers specifically tracking that certain tag.

Comment: "System tables" ***are*** in the SQL standard.  See the volume on INFORMATION_SCHEMA.  I don't even want to address "supposing" when there is nothing supposed to be supposed because the answer is already in the OP's question (10).

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a "matrix" of rows and columns, with a 0/1 or maybe true/false in each cell, indicating whether a column changed, then you may simply join the two tables by primary key:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN t1.col1 = t2.col1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS col1,
    CASE WHEN t1.col2 = t2.col2 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS col2,
    ...      -- other columns
FROM TableA_backup1 t1
INNER JOIN TableA_backup2 t2
    ON t1.pk = t2.pk
ORDER BY
    t1.pk;
```

This doesn't take into account the possibility that rows may have been lost or added in going from one backup snapshot to the other.  But, in this case, if two rows don't match at all, we can't really do a comparison of the column values anyway.

Comment: Actually I was doing the same thing but if we have number of columns then we need to add case statements for all the columns.

Comment: @JohnM : Then try to execute a dynamic sql query

Comment: @JohnM ,I think above script is good,you hv only 10 columns. You can put condition in where clause also.Else you can explain the complete scenario like why you will take back up.if  there is another calculation then again you will take back up.for how long.Why don't you update one column